# Online Ancien-Français or Moyen-Français dictionary?

Tags: ressources, ancien-français, dictionnaires, moyen-français

[*Dictionnaires d'autrefois*](https://artfl-project.uchicago.edu/content/dictionnaires-dautrefois) is a good free online resource for 17<sup>th</sup> through 20<sup>th</sup> centuries French dictionaries, but **are there any free online Old or Middle French dictionaries**, such as for the 14<sup>th</sup> (or earlier) centuries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Godefroy dictionary covers French from the 9<sup>th</sup> to the 15<sup>th</sup> centuries. It is available on-line [here](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/isnelt%C3%A9), among other invaluable resources: